# Email inbox integration

Tags: iphone, email

It's possible to create an app based on email.

I have to send message and get it's reply. i searching on the internet and i read that for sending email  via SMTP i have to use external library, but what about the inbox?

thx a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the current SDK, you have no access to the built-in Mail.app's data (messages or settings) whatsoever.

Comment: we have access to the inbox or we can only send messages via the default form?